# Persisting Java Beans

Tags: java, jvm, javabeans

I am new to Java Beans. I have read that in order for the Java Beans to be persisted  their class has to extend the Serializable class. Till when do they remain persisted ? Is it till the JVM is restarted ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you have persisted the data.

If  you have persisted data into a file then it will remain till you delete the file explicitly. This file could be used to reconstruct the object whenever required.

If you persist data over a wire and reconstruct the object again then it will remain depending on its scope (Garbage collection) and will definitely be removed once JVM is killed.

Answer (score 1):

Persistence means saving them to the database. We have many ORM(Object Relational Mapping) libraries in java like Hibernate,Data Nucleus,etc . You can persist the Java bean object in to the database using the ORM libraries and when you fetch from database again you can have the collection of Java Bean objects.

Comment: Persistence doesnt necessarily mean saving it to the database. It is one option.They could be persisted into a file by serializing and then deserialized to obtain the object back. You may have Entity Beans in your project which do not necessarily map to a table in the database but can be used to store data into a data storage location either memory temporary cache or as Vineet mentioned in a file.

Comment: My Pleasure.Thank you for your contribution.